# É possível criar objeto dentro de objeto em uma class com constructor?

Tags: javascript, json

Estou tentando criar uma class Cliente que tem os seguintes parâmetros:

```
{
"data": {
            "name": "Yuri Moura",
            "cpf": "123.456.789-00",
            "status": "Ativo",
            "contact": {
                "email": "contato@yuri.com",
                "tel": "(00) 0000-0000"
            },
        }
}
```

Estou tentando dessa forma, mas não sei como criar um objeto dentro do objeto num constructor:

```
class Cliente{
    constructor(name, cpf, contact, status) {
        this.name = name
        this.cpf = cpf
        this.status = status
        this.contact = contact{
            this.email = email
            this.tel = tel
        }
    }
}

    function cadastrarCliente() {
        let name = document.getElementById('name')
        let cpf = document.getElementById('cpf')
        let email = document.getElementById('email')
        let tel = document.getElementById('tel')
        let status = document.getElementById('status')

        let cliente = new Cliente(
            name.value, 
            cpf.value, 
            email.value, 
            tel.value, 
            status.value)

        console.log(cliente)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode declarar um objeto anônimo (sem classe) dentro do seu construtor.

```
class Cliente{
    constructor(name, cpf, status, email, tel) {
        this.name = name
        this.cpf = cpf
        this.status = status
        this.contact = {
            email,
            tel
        }
    }
}
```

Agora se você quiser trabalhar com classes como você já está fazendo, irá precisar de um construtor para contact.

```
class Contact{
    constructor(email, tel) {
        this.email = email
        this.tel = tel
    }
}

class Cliente{
    constructor(name, cpf, status, email, tel) {
        this.name = name
        this.cpf = cpf
        this.status = status
        this.contact = new Contact(email, tel)
    }
}
```

Comment: Utilizando como objeto anônimo consegui recuperar os parâmetros, obrigado!